# Is every nowhere dense closed set intersection of closures of non-intersecting open sets?

Tags: general-topology

This is a double-cross-post: I first asked [a question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/131366/127575) on cs.se, then [posted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/375150/41291) a particularly mathematical part of it to mathoverflow; after about month and a half I realised that I don't know answer to a simpler question which looks like an exercise from a general topology textbook. So I decided to ask it here.

Given two non-intersecting open sets, $U\cap V=\varnothing$, it is easy to show that the intersection $F=\bar U\cap\bar V$ of their closures is nowhere dense (i. e. has empty interior, that is, does not contain any open set).

Is the converse true? That is, is any nowhere dense closed set $F$ intersection of closures of two non-intersecting open sets?

Comment: As far as general topology goes, there is a reasonable class of topological spaces (called *irreducible*) where every two non-empty open sets have non-empty intersection, so this cannot be the case in general. This is the case for, say, $\Bbb C^n$ endowed with Zariski topology. However, these spaces aren't usually metrizable (because they aren't Hausdorff as soon as there are at least two points).

Comment: What if we add $T_2$ to the problem statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb N$, and let $\tau=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{U\subseteq\Bbb N:0\in U\}$; $\tau$ is a topology on $X$. $\{1\}$ is closed and nowhere dense but it cannot be the intersection of the closures of two disjoint, non-empty open sets, because the space doesn’t **have** two disjoint, non-empty open sets.